# How do I use a versioned COM interface from C#?

Tags: .net, com-interop

How do I make instances of and calls to COM components that have been extended?

I have used a third-party COM component (XRawFile2.dll from Finnigan/ Thermo Scientific) for many years in a [mass spectrometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_spectrometry)-related application written in .NET (mixed VB.NET and C#) for accessing raw spectrum data. This has worked well.

However, this COM component has been extended by way of interface inheritance. Expressed in IDL (extracted using the [OLE/COM Object Viewer](http://www.microsoft.com/DownLoads/details.aspx?FamilyID=5233b70d-d9b2-4cb5-aeb6-45664be858b6&displaylang=en) [OleView.Exe]):

```
interface IXRawfile3 : IXRawfile2 {
.
.

interface IXRawfile2 : IXRawfile {
.
.

interface IXRawfile : IDispatch {
.
.

coclass XRawfile {
    [default] interface IXRawfile;
};
```

The full extracted [IDL for XRawFile2.dll](http://pmortensen.eu/1/until2039-12-31/SO/IDLforXRawfile2.html) is available (HTML page with <pre>).

I want to use a function available in the new interface (IXRawfile3),

```
GetMassListRangeFromScanNum()
```

instead of

```
GetMassListFromScanNum()
```

in the original interface (IXRawfile).

I have no trouble creating an instance of XRawFile and calling GetMassListFromScanNum().

But I can't get it to work with GetMassListRangeFromScanNum(). For instance, using GetMassListRangeFromScanNum() for an instance of XRawFile gives this compile error:

```
    Error 1 'XRAWFILE2Lib.XRawfile' does not contain a
    definition for 'GetMassListRangeFromScanNum' and no
    extension method 'GetMassListRangeFromScanNum' accepting a
    first argument of type 'XRAWFILE2Lib.XRawfile' could be
    found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
    reference?)
```

The [tryout C# source code](http://pmortensen.eu/1/until2039-12-31/SO/XCaliburAccess.cs.html) is also available.

Platform: Windows XP 64 bit SP2. Visual Studio 2008. The interop file for XRawFile2.dll was created by Visual Studio 2008 in the normal manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try casting your instance of XRawFile to IXRawfile3

e.g.

```
( (IXRawfile3) myRawFile ).GetMassListRangeFromScanNum()
```

This should do a query interface on the COM object, asking it for the IXRawfile3 interface.  (Assuming the typelib you have imported does match the implementation of XRawfile)

Comment: That actually worked. Thanks! The returned data points were also as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the following statement (for version 2.2):

```
MSFileReader_XRawfile rawfile = new MSFileReader_XRawfile();
```

This could simply give you an intense.

You may call any of the methods later.

Comment: Re *"an intense"*: Do you mean *"an instance"*?